# Register all inputs inside a multi-page data table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a datatable in which I've added checkboxes for my users to select various options.  Unfortunately, the only inputs that shiny seems to see are ones that have been displayed in the table.  So if I have multiple pages, I'm only able to see the first 10 inputs.

In the example below, I've printed all of the inputs that I can see registered above the datatable object. At the moment, I only see the first 10 inputs (A - J).  I'd like to be able to see all 26 when the table first loads (without having to toggle through the pages).

In my actual application, I have multiple columns of checkboxes, so row selection wouldn't be sufficient.  Any tips or suggestions on how to register all 26 inputs at once?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyInput <- function (FUN, id_base, suffix, label = "", ...) 
{
  inputId <- paste0(id_base, suffix)
  args <- list(...)
  args <- c(list(label = label), args)
  args <- lapply(args, function(a) rep(a, length.out = length(inputId)))
  rv <- character(length(inputId))
  for (i in seq_along(rv)) {
    this_arg <- lapply(args, `[`, i)
    ctrl <- do.call(FUN, c(list(inputId = inputId[i]), this_arg))
    rv[i] <- as.character(ctrl)
  }
  rv
}

X <- data.frame(id = LETTERS, 
                selected = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 
                                  size = length(LETTERS), 
                                  replace = TRUE))

X$IsSelected <- 
  shinyInput(
    shiny::checkboxInput, 
    id_base = "new_input_", 
    suffix = X$id, 
    value = X$selected
  )

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    verbatimTextOutput("value_check"),
    textOutput("input_a_value"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("dt")
  ), 
  
  server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
    
    Data <- reactiveValues(
      X = X
    )
    
    output$value_check <- 
      renderPrint({
        sort(names(input))
      })
    
    output$dt <- 
      DT::renderDataTable({
        
        
        DT::datatable(X, 
                      selection = "none", 
                      escape = FALSE, 
                      filter = "top", 
                      #rownames = FALSE, 
                      class = "compact cell-border", 
                      options = list(preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                                     drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')))
      })
  })
)
```

### ADDENDUM

This next example is a bit more complex, but illustrates a bit more of the motivation for the question.  It seems the biggest issue is that I would like to utilize buttons such as "select all." Additionally, I'm not processing any actions immediately when a box is interacted with. Instead, the user makes their selections, and the selections are not saved until the "Save Selections" button is clicked.

What is happening is I click on the "Select All" button, and it checks all of the boxes for inputs that have been drawn already. If I've only viewed the first page of the table, it updates only those inputs, and none of the inputs on the next few pages. This is really the behavior I need to change.

```
# Set up environment ------------------------------------------------
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(magrittr)

# Example of data coming from the database. -------------------------

set.seed(pi^2)

SourceData <- 
  data.frame(sample_id = 1:25, 
             is_selected = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 25, replace = TRUE))


# Support Functions -------------------------------------------------
# These would exist, for example, in an internal package

shinyInput <- function (FUN, id_base, suffix, label = "", ...) 
{
  inputId <- paste0(id_base, suffix)
  args <- list(...)
  args <- c(list(label = label), args)
  args <- lapply(args, function(a) rep(a, length.out = length(inputId)))
  rv <- character(length(inputId))
  for (i in seq_along(rv)) {
    this_arg <- lapply(args, `[`, i)
    ctrl <- do.call(FUN, c(list(inputId = inputId[i]), this_arg))
    rv[i] <- as.character(ctrl)
  }
  rv
}

prepareDataForDisplay <- function(Data){
  Data$is_selected <- 
    shinyInput(shiny::checkboxInput, 
               id_base = "is_selected_", 
               suffix = Data$sample_id, 
               value = Data$is_selected)
  
  Data
}

# User Interface ----------------------------------------------------

ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    verbatimTextOutput("value_check"), 
    
    actionButton(inputId = "btn_saveSelection", 
                 label = "Save Selection"), 
    actionButton(inputId = "btn_selectAll", 
                 label = "Select All"),
    actionButton(inputId = "btn_unselectAll", 
                 label = "Unselect All"),
    actionButton(inputId = "btn_restoreDefault", 
                 label = "Restore Default (select odd only)"),
    
    DT::dataTableOutput("dt")
  )

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------

server <- 
  shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
    
    # Event Observers -----------------------------------------------
    
    observeEvent(
      input$btn_selectAll, 
      {
        check_input <- names(input)[grepl("is_selected_", names(input))]
        
        lapply(check_input, 
               function(ci){
                 updateCheckboxInput(session = session, 
                                     inputId = ci, 
                                     value = TRUE)
               })
      }
    )
    
    observeEvent(
      input$btn_unselectAll, 
      {
        check_input <- names(input)[grepl("is_selected_", names(input))]
        
        lapply(check_input, 
               function(ci){
                 updateCheckboxInput(session = session, 
                                     inputId = ci, 
                                     value = FALSE)
               })
      }
    )
    
    observeEvent(
      input$btn_restoreDefault,
      {
        check_input <- names(input)[grepl("is_selected_", names(input))]

        lapply(check_input, 
               function(ci){
                 id <- as.numeric(sub("is_selected_", "", ci))
                 
                 updateCheckboxInput(session = session, 
                                     inputId = ci, 
                                     value = id %% 2 == 1)
               })
      }
    )
    
    observeEvent(
      input$btn_saveSelection,
      {
        check_input <- names(input)[grepl("is_selected_", names(input))]
        
        id <- as.numeric(sub("is_selected_", "", check_input))

        for (i in seq_along(check_input)){
          SourceData$is_selected[SourceData$sample_id == id[i]] <- 
            input[[check_input[i]]]
        }

        # At this point, I would also save changes to the remote database.
        
        DT::replaceData(proxy = dt_proxy, 
                        data = prepareDataForDisplay(SourceData))
      }
    )
    
    # Output elements -----------------------------------------------
    
    output$value_check <- 
      renderPrint({
        sort(names(input))
      })
    
    output$dt <- 
      DT::renderDataTable({
        SourceData %>% 
          prepareDataForDisplay() %>% 
          DT::datatable(selection = "none", 
                        escape = FALSE, 
                        filter = "top", 
                        class = "compact cell-border", 
                        options = list(preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                                       drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')))
      })
    
    dt_proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy("dt")
    
  })

# Run the application -----------------------------------------------

shinyApp(
  ui = ui, 
  server = server
)
```

Comment: I guess you are aware of this, but you could work around this problem, as you know the initial state of the inputs. You could e.g. initialize a reactive `data.frame` and sync it with the inputs for downstream use.

Comment: An earlier version of my application did that, actually. But then I ran into problems with saving selections, updating the reactive `data.frame`, which prompted redrawing the DataTable object (slow), etc.  If I'm not able to get a satisfactory solution for this, the eventual work around will probably be just setting the option `pageLength = nrow(X)`

Comment: You could avoid re-rendering the table via `replaceData` see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69344974/dt-dynamically-change-column-values-based-on-selectinput-from-another-column-in/69389649#69389649).

Comment: `replaceData` is what I use, because I'm not using the reactive `data.frame`.  Am I incorrect in my understanding that a reactive `data.frame` and `replaceData` don't mix?

Comment: If you'd like, I can string together a small example of the full scope of what I'm trying to do.  It just didn't feel very MWE for the question at hand.

Comment: In the example I provided (and the one linked below it) I'm using `replaceData` along with a `reactive`. You just need to avoid placing reactives in the `renderDT` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround based on your addendum (not sure if you need the changes regarding `btn_restoreDefault` and `btn_saveSelection`), but the general procedure should be clear:

```
# Set up environment ------------------------------------------------
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(magrittr)

# Example of data coming from the database. -------------------------

set.seed(pi^2)

SourceData <- 
  data.frame(sample_id = 1:25, 
             is_selected = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 25, replace = TRUE))


# Support Functions -------------------------------------------------
# These would exist, for example, in an internal package

shinyInput <- function (FUN, id_base, suffix, label = "", ...) 
{
  inputId <- paste0(id_base, suffix)
  args <- list(...)
  args <- c(list(label = label), args)
  args <- lapply(args, function(a) rep(a, length.out = length(inputId)))
  rv <- character(length(inputId))
  for (i in seq_along(rv)) {
    this_arg <- lapply(args, `[`, i)
    ctrl <- do.call(FUN, c(list(inputId = inputId[i]), this_arg))
    rv[i] <- as.character(ctrl)
  }
  rv
}

prepareDataForDisplay <- function(Data){
  Data$is_selected <- 
    shinyInput(shiny::checkboxInput, 
               id_base = "is_selected_", 
               suffix = Data$sample_id, 
               value = Data$is_selected)
  
  Data
}

# User Interface ----------------------------------------------------

ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    verbatimTextOutput("value_check"), 
    
    actionButton(inputId = "btn_saveSelection", 
                 label = "Save Selection"), 
    actionButton(inputId = "btn_selectAll", 
                 label = "Select All"),
    actionButton(inputId = "btn_unselectAll", 
                 label = "Unselect All"),
    actionButton(inputId = "btn_restoreDefault", 
                 label = "Restore Default (select odd only)"),
    
    DT::dataTableOutput("dt")
  )

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------

server <- 
  shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
    
    # Event Observers -----------------------------------------------
    
    observeEvent(
      input$btn_selectAll, 
      {
        TmpData <- SourceData
        TmpData$is_selected <- TRUE
        replaceData(dt_proxy, prepareDataForDisplay(TmpData))
      }
    )
    
    observeEvent(
      input$btn_unselectAll, 
      {
        TmpData <- SourceData
        TmpData$is_selected <- FALSE
        replaceData(dt_proxy, prepareDataForDisplay(TmpData))
      }
    )
    
    observeEvent(
      input$btn_restoreDefault, 
      {
        replaceData(dt_proxy, prepareDataForDisplay(SourceData))
      }
    )
    
    observeEvent(
      input$btn_saveSelection,
      {
        
        check_input <- names(input)[grepl("is_selected_", names(input))]
        
        id <- as.numeric(sub("is_selected_", "", check_input))
        
        TmpData <- SourceData 
        
        for (i in seq_along(check_input)){
          TmpData$is_selected[TmpData$sample_id == id[i]] <- 
            input[[check_input[i]]]
        }
        
        # At this point, I would also save changes to the remote database.
        
        DT::replaceData(proxy = dt_proxy, 
                        data = prepareDataForDisplay(TmpData))
      }
    )
    
    # Output elements -----------------------------------------------
    
    output$value_check <- 
      renderPrint({
        sort(names(input))
      })
    
    output$dt <- 
      DT::renderDataTable({
        SourceData %>% 
          prepareDataForDisplay() %>% 
          DT::datatable(selection = "none", 
                        escape = FALSE, 
                        filter = "top", 
                        class = "compact cell-border", 
                        options = list(preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                                       drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')))
      })
    
    dt_proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy("dt")
    
  })

# Run the application -----------------------------------------------

shinyApp(
  ui = ui, 
  server = server
)
```

Comment: Hello @ismirsehregal.
I have exactly the same issue with Shiny DataTable not displaying (and updating) the inputs beyond the current page (and I have of course more than one page).
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64637582/r-shiny-dt-checkboxes-on-top-to-tick-untick-all-the-checkboxes-below/

Comment: The (workaround) solution mentioned by @Benjamin in a comment to adjust the `pageLength` parameter in `renderDataTable` with the total number of rows of the table is not satisfying. Indeed, in my case at least, I want to be able to use the filter and this filter has, by definition actually, exactly the same effects as the pagination (it limits the number of visible rows). And as Shiny DataTable only works with what it sees, we go back to the same issue.

Comment: So, if we sum up, is this basically the solution to solve the limited-display-and-update issue: to feed the Shiny inputs from a dynamically updated data.frame (or any other relevant object -- here I understood `dataTableProxy` should be used) storing their value via `replaceData`?

Comment: @Olivier7121 sorry for the late answer. Yes, your summary is correct. Please check my related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70095544/9841389) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69389649/9841389).

Comment: No apologies needed, @ismirsehregal, really! I had 2 intensive programming sessions on the 9th and 10th of July and finally got exactly what I was looking for thanks to your workaround. Thanks a lot! And thanks also for the 2 other links in your comment.
I posted "my" solution in the original thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64637582/r-shiny-dt-checkboxes-on-top-to-tick-untick-all-the-checkboxes-below/65641398#65641398).